# How do I run a .lua script in Notepad++?

Tags: lua, notepad++

I have a very basic .lua file saved in a folder, with just the code 
`print("Hello world")` 
I additionally have the standalone lua interpreter downloaded, but it is beyond me how to successfully run my code. I put all the files of the interpreter in the same folder but when I use F5 to run the program I see no text in the interpreter.

Comment: Have you set up the files to be run with the interpreter by default? When you do you simply gotta double-click

Answer (score 1):

Run Notepad++.
On the menu select: Run -> Run.. (F5).
Insert: `C:\path\to\lua.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Now you can run your scripts by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with NppExec plugin:

```
SET interpreter = F:\lua\lua53.exe
SET exec = "$(interpreter)" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
NPP_SAVE
$(exec)
if $(EXITCODE) != 0 goto exit
NPP_CONSOLE 0
NPP_RUN cmd /C "cmd /C $(exec) && pause"
:exit
```

Answer (score 1):

KaMehHb's answer is correct, but one thing to add is either delete this line or change it to 1 if you want the console to stay up.

`NPP_CONSOLE 0`

to

`NPP_CONSOLE 1`